# Pause For-Loop for 1 second in C++

Tags: c++, sleep

I have an loop, but it goes to fast. I need something simple and easy to use, to  pause it for 1 sec in each loop.

```cpp
for(int i=0;i<=500;i++){
   cout << "Hello number : " << i;
   //i need here something like a pause for 1 sec
}
```

Comment: Surely you can pause for 1 second, but is this what you really want? I'm concerned what you're looking for is maybe *how to use a debugger?* instead.

Comment: See the example using `sleep_for` on this page:  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Comment: take a look at unistd.h sleep

Comment: C++11 and later, use `std::this_thread::sleep_for()`.   Before C++11, the options are implementation dependent (vary with host OS and compiler).

Comment: take a look at the boost libraries, boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(someSeconds));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) is exactly what you're looking for.

```
for(int i=0;i<=500;i++){
    cout << "Hello number : " << i;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
}
```

To use it like that, you need to include `<chrono>` and `<thread>` and then add `using namespace std::chrono_literals;`. It also requires `c++11` enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you use windows platform this may help:

```cpp
#include <windows.h> //winapi header  

Sleep(1000);//function to make app to pause for a second and continue after that
```

Comment: This is only the easiest way if you're on Windows.

Comment: Which, I just realized you're the OP, so you would know if you are, I guess. Still, this solution only applies to Windows. If anyone else reading this is on any other platform, this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Sleep(n) is a prepared method. To use this method do not forget to add "windows.h" header file as well and remember 'n' is the millisecond you may wish to delay the code execution. A simple code which repeats "Hello world!" can be seen:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
     Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This method was already proposed in one of the other answers